# How to deal with 'A or B' in multichoice question marking?

Tags: python

I have 7 different classes and a grand total of 309 students this term. I am supposed to give them homework each week. I use a multi-choice marking program, Formreturn (which I can highly recommend), but even so, with so many students, it is too much printing each week! Save the trees, save paper!

Python to the rescue! (Although I am not a computer person.)

I have written 2 routines, one collects email texts, the other writes the data to my excel results file. They work in my test run.

Sometimes, 2 answers are needed: A and B, that's not a problem, just write AB.
Sometimes, A or B is correct. (Formreturn answer key just write A|B)

Given this kind of answers text: number,name,answer, answer,answer ...

> 1825010101,徐豆豆,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J

and this kind of answer key: filler, filler, correctanswer, correctanswer, ...
(filler just to keep the loop numbers equal)

> p,p,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J

Let's say A could be A or B.

Question: Can you see any way to deal with that?

I will avoid this situation for the present.

The code that does the checking is:

```
studentScores = {}

# now check the answers

for i in range(0, len(tidyDataAsList)):
    count = 0
    studentNumber = tidyDataAsList[i][0]
    print('student number is ' + studentNumber)
    for j in range(2, len(tidyDataAsList[i])):
        print('Student answer is ' + tidyDataAsList[i][j])
        print('Correct answer is ' + tidyanswerDataList[j])
        if tidyDataAsList[i][j] == tidyanswerDataList[j]:
            count += 1
            print('count is ' + str(count))
            studentScores[studentNumber] = count
```

Then just write the dictionary values to excel. (I can just about manage that.)

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the answer key says the answer is `A|B`, you can do this:

```
allCorrect = tidyanswerDataList[j].split('|')
for correct in allCorrect:
    if tidyDataAsList[i][j] == correct:
        # usual code for a correct answer
        break
```

Or, more concisely:

```
if tidyDataAsList[i][j] in tidyanswerDataList[j].split('|')
    # usual code for a correct answer
    break
```

If there is no `|` in the answer key, the result will be the same as your original code (because `split('|')` will return the whole string).

Comment: Thank you very much, and excuse me for asking as a blatant beginner, but where should I stick this bit of code? I think just after "print('Correct answer is ' + tidyanswerDataList[j])  and before "if tidyDataAsList[i][j] == tidyanswerDataList[j]:" Is that right?

Comment: @Pedroski: This code is a replacement for `if tidyDataAsList[i][j] == tidyanswerDataList[j]:`.  Instead of asking "Do these strings match exactly" we ask "Is this string contained in that other string".

Comment: Thanks again! Big test of this code tomorrow, I'll try it out for real!

Comment: Thanks again. It took me while to figure out how this works. I think I have finally understood it! Works great!

Comment: @Pedroski: You're welcome.  Since this answer solved your question, you can "Accept"  it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I am always amazed when things work! I never thought I could get it working!

| stands for OR

correctAnswers = ['a|b|c', 'n|j', 's', 'w', 'e', 'r']
myAnswers1 = ['c', 'j', 's', 'w', 'e', 'r']

```
for i in range(0, len(correctAnswers)):
        if myAnswers1[i] in correctAnswers[i].split('|'):
               count +=1
        print('Correct answer is ' + correctAnswers[i])
        print('My answer was ' + myAnswers1[i])
        print('Count is ' + str(count))
```

Correct answer is a|b|c
My answer was c
Count is 1
Correct answer is n|j
My answer was j
Count is 2
Correct answer is s
My answer was s
Count is 3
Correct answer is w
My answer was w
Count is 4
Correct answer is e
My answer was e
Count is 5
Correct answer is r
My answer was r
Count is 6